# Model adequacy test in curvilinear regression model

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, interpretation

I've the idea regarding the model adequacy test of linear regression model. Curvilinear model being different from the linear model, how the model adequacy test of curvilinear regression model can be tested?

Comment: Because "curvilinear regression model" could refer to a great many different things, and the test of fit (or model adequacy) depends on the model, please provide some specifics of your model and how you are fitting it.

Comment: I'm trying it in "logistic growth model".